# ¿stream de audio con B2 y andorid studio?

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth

estoy tratando de establecer una transmisión de datos(enviar un sonido) hacia mi teléfono mediante un modulo B2 HC-05/06, y quisiera saber si es posible que mi teléfono reproduzca el audio en stream, si es así, seria de gran ayuda si me dieran alguna idea de como hacerlo, un diagrama de flujo o alguna pagina que me sirva de guía.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo este ejemplo funcionando , de como reproducir stream mediante android studio

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 try {
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://10.0.2.2:8000/;stream.mp3");
 mediaPlayer.prepare();
 mediaPlayer.start();
 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (SecurityException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

}

@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 return true;
 }

}
```

Lo que deben de agregar es:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
```

Y las siguiente lineas:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://10.0.2.2:8000/;stream.mp3");
 mediaPlayer.prepare();
 mediaPlayer.start();
```

Espero mi palomita :D

Comment: lo revisare, muchas gracias